# C-icap - how to cross compiling?

Tags: linux, cross-compiling, icap

I've been trying to cross compile **the C-icap on ARM Cortex A8** (Linux - Arago 2011.09 am335x). 
I downloaded the c-icap from http://c-icap.sourceforge.net/download.html 
I have arm-arago-linux-gnueabi-gcc and arm-arago-linux-gnueabi-g++.

I don't know what I have to write:

```
 ./configure .........
```

Could you help me???

```
./configure   --prefix=/usr/local/c_icap  --host=arm-linux\
CC=/opt/arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-arago-linux-gnueabi-gcc \
--enable-gnuregex --enable-async-io=80 --enable-cache-digests \
--enable-err-language="zh-cn" --enable-default-err-language="zh-cn"\
--enable-epoll --disable-internal-dns --enable-kill-parent-hack
```

What is wrong???

Answer (score 0):

You can cross compile c_icap as shown below.

Check whether the toolcahin path has been exported else export it

```
export PATH=/opt/arm-arago-linux-gnueabi/bin:$PATH
```

First configure c_icap. To avoid tests that will fail if we are cross compiling, we have to set the values as yes or no.(**ac_cv_fcntl** & **ac_cv_10031b_ipc_sem**)

```
ac_cv_fcntl=yes ac_cv_10031b_ipc_sem=yes ./configure --prefix=/ --host=arm-arago-linux-gnueabi
```

Next compile c_icap

```
make
```

Next install it

```
make install DESTDIR=/usr/local/c_icap
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88551/discussion-on-answer-by-ashwanth-selvam-c-icap-how-to-cross-compiling).